# How do I create PDF file in asp.net by fetching the data from the database?

Tags: asp.net

I am doing project in asp.net.I have a problem with creating PDF file.I have to create PDF file for generating Question Paper according to the users requirement.

```
    I have searched in internet for above question but I could not find proper answer for creating PDF by fetching the data from database.I am using SQL database for my project.Can anyone help me to solve this problem ?
```

Comment: what you want to do exactly? Create PDF or fetch data from SQL?

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564260/saving-data-from-sql-server-database-into-a-pdf-file?rq=1

Comment: try
https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-PDF-Report-from-database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Saving data from sql server Database into a PDF file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32564260/saving-data-from-sql-server-database-into-a-pdf-file)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927675/convert-datatable-to-pdf